# Cross Domain Cookie not Working

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm using the code below to set cookies on my site. It's on blog.domain.com but I need the cookies to go across all of our domains. I'm under the impression that using '.domain.com' should work, but it's just setting the domain as 'blog.domain.com' and refusing to put the cookies across all domains. Anyone spot a bug I'm not noticing?

```
function set_cookie ( cookie_name, cookie_value,
lifespan_in_days, valid_domain )
{
    var domain_string = "; domain=" + valid_domain
    document.cookie = cookie_name +
                   "=" + encodeURIComponent( cookie_value ) +
                   ";max-age=" + 60 * 60 *
                   24 * lifespan_in_days; +
                   ";domain=.domain.com;path=/;";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra semicolon in your code, after `lifespan_in_days` -- that's preventing the domain from being appended.

```
function set_cookie (cookie_name, cookie_value,
    lifespan_in_days, valid_domain ) {
    var domain_string = "; domain=" + valid_domain
    document.cookie = cookie_name +
        "=" + encodeURIComponent( cookie_value ) +
        ";max-age=" + 60 * 60 *
        24 * lifespan_in_days +
        ";domain=.domain.com;path=/;";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed that :(